# How to xml schema file to json in php

Tags: php, json, xml, xsd

i have a xml schema file `testing.xml` and i want to convert it to json in php, file has below content

**testing.xml**

```
<DataTable xmlns="https://whatever/">
    <script id="test-script"/>

  <xs:schema xmlns="" xmlns:xs="https://whatever/" xmlns:msdata="whatever" id="test">

    <xs:element name="test" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Appt" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">

      <xs:complexType>

        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">

          <xs:element name="Appt">

            <xs:complexType>

              <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

                <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>

              </xs:sequence>

            </xs:complexType>

          </xs:element>

        </xs:choice>

      </xs:complexType>

    </xs:element>

  </xs:schema>

</DataTable>
```

But when i follow the php xml to json converting process then i am getting the below output:

```
{"DataTable":{"script":{"@id":"test-script"}}}
```

I am not getting the correct json, can anybody help me to come out from this please

Comment: Not sure the C# tag and information are usefull here as it can get some one confused. From _"i have a c# dataset xml file "_ To _"I have a XML file"_ seems clear to me. So the question is about "PHP convert XML to JSON".

Comment: if you see the xml code then you will understand or try to converting it in php

Comment: maybe that php component ignores inline xsd, in which case the json is correct.

Comment: @Crowcoder problem is the tag follow by`:`, i thought some one know this type of json conversion in php, last option i have to replace that tag manually

Comment: That is the schema of the DataTable, it is not part of the data. You must have exported with the schema option.

Comment: @Crowcoder like ? please show me the example

Comment: I don't think you understand my comment. I have no example, I'm trying to explain that your xml has only ONE data element. The rest is schema information. I don't know what php component you are using but it seems like it understands xsd schemas and it is correctly omitting that section from the json. Please read a little about xsd schema.

Comment: @Crowcoder thanks :) you are right did not get you but i am reading about xsd schema